# Google Cast iOS SDK 4.4.4 - no device discovery

Tags: ios, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

After updating to cast sdk 4.4.4, the device discovery stopped working on iOS simulator. I dont have a physical device to check if it works there.
Tested on simulators, running iOS 12.2 and 10.3.1

The Logger shows this message: Invalid BBSID with WiFi network for MDNS scanner

If I downgrade the sdk to 3.4.0 - no such problem is present. 
Is it a bug or casting is now not supported through the simulator?

Edit: I tried it on a real device and there are no problems with the discovery there. The problem remains on simulators only.

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that the scanner doesn’t get network ID. On 4.4.4, it shouldn’t be bssid though — we’ll fix it. As for simulator, it should work, just tried with xcode 10 though.. but from the logic, it shouldn't make a difference between xcode 10 and 11.

Comment: I'm using XCode 10.2.1. Tried various simulators with iOS 12.2 and 10.3.1 and none of them has the device discovery working on sdk 4.4.4 (no bluetooth). The very same configuration works with no problem on sdk 3.4.0

Comment: Can you turn on the verbose logging of SDK, and send us logs?https://developers.google.com/cast/support#report_issues